# R guessing game syntax

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having trouble with proper bracket syntax when making a guessing game. Here is a brief example of my code

```
number_result <- readline(prompt = "Choose a number btwn 1 & 100: ")
input <- 0
rand <- sample(seq(1,100), size = 1)

input = number_result


while(input != rand){

  if(input < rand){
    print("Higher!")
  }
  else if(input > rand){
    print("Lower!")
  }
  else(input = rand){
  return(print("You got it!"))
}
    }
```

My error is:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"  }
  else(input = rand){"
>     return(print("You got it!"))
[1] "You got it!"
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>
```

Comment: Do you mean to have a condition for your third `else` statement? If so, use `else if`, if not, then use `else{` and no need to include the `(input = rand)` part. Additionally, __`R`__ uses double equals `==` for logical equality checks, not single equals `=` as you've typed. It suffices to type `print('You got it!')` without the `return` wrapper

Comment: Thank you, I think the logic equality "==" was the biggest thing - i'm still using the return() wrapper to end the while loop though. I think I will create a function that it returns to until the user is able to properly guess the number.

Answer (score -2):

No return needed because you didn't define a function. You must also specify a stopping condition! Otherwise your while will run forever.
try this

```
      number_result <- readline(prompt = "Choose a number btwn 1 & 100: ")
      input <- 0
      rand <- sample(seq(1,100), size = 1)

      input = number_result
while(input != rand){
  if(input < rand){
    print("Higher!")
  } else if(input > rand){
    print("Lower!")
  } else {
    print("You got it!")
  }
  input <- input + 1
}
```

Comment: There is a more serious fundamental problem which you have missed

Comment: OP also wants a `while` loop

Comment: Thank you this was still helpful